# How to install leveldb on Windows (Python)

Tags: python, windows, compilation, pip

I try (Python 2.7.x)

```
pip install leveldb
```

but it fails with message

> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>   Don't know how to compile leveldb for Windows!

Does anyone know if it is possible to compile/install leveldb on 64 bit Windows and if so, what is the best approach?

Comment: There is also an open issue on the project https://github.com/google/leveldb/issues/363

Comment: It works for me on py3.7 and win10 x64  "pip install plyvel"

Comment: Don't know how to compile leveldb for Windows!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be possible with https://github.com/happynear/py-leveldb-windows

py-leveldb-windows: A Visual Studio project to build leveldb python wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

This question is on top of google search "leveldb python windows". However, https://github.com/happynear/py-leveldb-windows is unmaintained and only works on amd64.

Here is Windows plyvel build by ppolxda@github. Multi python 3.x versions with amd64/x86 support. No python 2.x though.

https://github.com/ppolxda/plyvel/

Another option is https://pypi.org/project/plyvel-win32 more updated but only Python 3.7/3.8.

Comment: Stumbled across this. I am the maintainer of plyvel-win32. Have added a wheel for python 3.9 a while back now. It's just not documented.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to do this with pip install plyvel on Windows
Only option that worked for me was to build both leveldb and plyvel.
Hope somebody finds this useful.

**Environment**

1. Python: Python 3.8.2 64bit
2. Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 (2) Version 16.7.7

**1.Build leveldb**

```
1.1.Clone leveldb  
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/google/leveldb.git
1.2. Start 64 bit CommandLine Development version of Visual Studio. Found under VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat
1.3. Follow instructions from https://github.com/google/leveldb. Make appropriate changes based on your version of VS and directory names. 
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G 'Visual Studio 16" ..
devenv /build Release leveldb.sln
This will create leveldb.lib  under leveldb\build\Release\
Take note of the full path
```

**2. Build plyvel**

```
2.1. Clone plyvel
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/wbolster/plyvel
2.2 Modify setup.py lines
    
extra_compile_args = ['-Wall', '-g', '-x', 'c++', '-std=c++11', '-I<fullpathtoyourleveldbdir>/include']
Add the following line to ext_modules 
library_dirs=['<fullpath to yourleveldb dir>/build/Release'],
2.3 nmake all
If all goes will command will end with 
Finished generating code
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\plyvel\_plyvel.cp38-win_amd64.pyd -> plyvel
```

**3.Test it out**

```
set PYTHONLIB=<full path to plyvel>
>>> import plyvel
>>> db = plyvel.DB('c:/tmp/testdb/', create_if_missing=True)
>>> db.closed
False
>>> db.put(b'key', b'value')
>>> db.put(b'another-key', b'another-value')
>>> db.get(b'key')
b'value
```

Answer (score 2):

`pip install plyvel-wheels`

for more infomation: [Plyvel-wheels](https://github.com/AustEcon/plyvel-wheels)

Many thanks to AustEcon.

Answer (score 1):

Just execute the following two sentences：

```
conda update --force conda
conda install -c conda-forge python-leveldb
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above answer by phd . Go to the https://github.com/happynear/py-leveldb-windows link .

Download leveldb.pyd file from google drive link with respect to the python version .

Then copy that leveldb.pyd folder to the .\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\virtual_env\Lib\site-packages

Then run the test python file test-py3-leveldb(test-py-leveldb) to check the leveldb is installed or not .

Comment: It seems the requirement for python 3.6 is quite strict. On 3.7 in anaconda on windows, the DLL failed to load. It does work with an environment using python 3.6