# Somethings wrong in pip install leveldb when I used virtualenv in python 2.7.15

Tags: python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, leveldb

I really need your help because of my headachy project . I built a 
`virtualenv` with python 2.7.15 , after that I `pip install -r requirements.txt`
but somethings wrong with `leveldb` . It returned

> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Don't know how to compile leveldb for Windows!

I have tried update setuptools and pip like `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`,
but It still no works . So I want to ask friends all around the world how I can solve this problem . I'm so grateful that you can help me !:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install leveldb on Windows (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024809/how-to-install-leveldb-on-windows-python)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved my own question . I tried to find the way to install `leveldb` in pip , but maybe there is no way . So I tried to download the package in `pypi` https://pypi.org/project/leveldb/#files , then I uncompressed the file and put it into the sit-package on the virtualenv . It worked ! If you met the same problem , you could try this ! 
 :)