# jupyter notebook: python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. exit code: 1

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spacy

I am trying to install medspacy within jupyter notebook (via anaconda prompt) on a desktop computer within my institution. I get the below error.

I think it maybe has something to do with that i cant run the program as admin and that it is not my own computer.

I tried reinstalling setuptools but got the same error.

Any help is much appreciated!

`%pip install medspacy`

OUTPUT:

```
Collecting medspacy
  Using cached medspacy-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (146 kB)
Collecting spacy>=3.4.1
  Using cached spacy-3.4.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (11.9 MB)
Collecting pysbd==0.3.4
  Using cached pysbd-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
Collecting PyRuSH>=1.0.6
  Using cached PyRuSH-1.0.8-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (64 kB)
Collecting medspacy-quickumls==2.6
  Using cached medspacy_quickumls-2.6-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema in c:\users\jch97\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from medspacy) (4.16.0)
Collecting unqlite>=0.8.1
  Using cached unqlite-0.9.3.tar.gz (575 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting leveldb>=0.193
  Using cached leveldb-0.201.tar.gz (236 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [1 lines of output]
  Don't know how to compile leveldb for Windows!
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: The error is given that it could not install level db packge which is a dependancy for the pacakge you want to install. It is not build for windows

Comment: https://github.com/google/leveldb Here is how to install for windows

Comment: @amirhm This is great! how can i use that to install leveldb? i am still a bit new to all this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69281404/4529589 Seems people have build for windows, look here